# TableViewController Delegate not getting Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So here's what I want happening. I have many tab bar items, and I have one particular item that says "share". When the user taps it, a share screen should pop up instead of me clicking on the item and seeing what's on that item's page.

To make it simple, I want an action to be called when I hit the tab bar icon. So I looked this up and found this delegate:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Within this delegate I want something to happen, like, NSLog(@"Something")
But this delegate never gets called. I've set the delegate in the .h and I've put this code in my TableViewController .m and my DisplayViewController.m

Both .h's have the delegate set. I don't know why it's not being called but I'll put my code here for interpretation anyway.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item.tag == 5)
    {

   NSLog(@"Something");

    }
}
```

and in my .h:

```
@interface PhotosTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>
```

Comment: Do you set the delegate of the tab bar to the object that instantiates the delegate protocol and method?

Comment: NSLog(@"Something") is coded correctly. I just forgot to add the " at the end of the question

Comment: ur using UITabBarController or UITabBar ? for which one u set delegate ?

Comment: What you're showing in your .h file doesn't set the delegate. That just tells the compiler that you intend to implement the delegate protocol.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you're clicking a TableViewCell then you should be using the TableViewDelegate's method for clicking and not the tab bar. That may be the answer, but I'd really need a clearer idea of what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

> Both .h's have the delegate set.

call   `yourTabBar.delegate = self;`

in your `TableViewController .m` or `DisplayViewController.m`  `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: When I try to create files for my tab bar controller and when i try to connect those files to the view controller, it rejects it. How can i go about setting its delegate to self now?

Comment: I cant get u.. could u please send ur sample code to ramshadram90@gmail.com ?

Comment: The thing is I haven't declared my TabBarController as an object yet. I can't create a file that inherits from UITabBarController and links with the TabBarController. I can make the file, but when I go to the properties of my tabbarcontroller, it won't allow me to use my *custom class*

Comment: could u please send ur sample code to ramshadram90@gmail.com ?